# bin-debug missing the html file cannot rebuild flex4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I cant seem to recreate my Main.html that is necessary to build from in flashbuilder4 I guess I can do it manually at cost of time but what a bore ! I'm sure this shoudl be possible.

Clean rebuilds most of this folder and then runnign the project get the error that it cant find Main.html grrrrrrrr

Comment: I am having the same issue. It seems that sometimes Flash Builder gets stuck in some kind of state where it doesn't recognize that the html file doesn't exist, and won't regenerate it. Sadly, none of the existing answers to this question work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using FB 4.5, but have had this happen on earlier versions of FB/FlxB, as well.  I've found that what causes this is that the index.template.html file in the html-template directory has gotten renamed to Main.html (or whatever the name of the Application file is in my project).  If the template file does not have '.template' in its name, the build process will not recognize that it needs to generate a file from it.

What has worked for me is either:

**The 'manual' way**
Go into the html-template file and rename the *.html file back to index.template.html.  Do a clean/build.

**The 'automatic' way**
Go into the project's Properties dialog, and navigate to the Flex Compiler pane.  Uncheck the 'Generate HTML wrapper file' and click Apply.  You will be warned that all of your files in the html-template directory will be destroyed.  This is important if you have customized them, but if you haven't, then don't worry about it.  If you *have* then copy your customizations to a text file for the time being.

Now, re-check the 'Generate HTML wrapper file' and click Apply.  The html-template directory will be repopulated, and this issue will (hopefully) be resolved.  If you had customizations to files in this directory, reapply them now.  Do a clean/build and you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

Is your html-Template directory empty?  If so, that is why bin-debug has no HTML files in it.  This happens on occasion, I never tracked down why, though.

You can get the default html-template files from here:

*[FlashBulderInstallDirectory]*\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.project_4.0.0.272416\resources\html-templates.zip

Unzip the file; copy the templates into your html-template directory.  Then clean the project and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you edtir the project right clicking on it and selecting properties, then select Flex Compiler and uncheck generate HTML wrapper file (or just uncheck Enable integration with web browser), this force Flex to regenerate the HTML wrapper files

Comment: In the current version of Flash Builder, this does nothing. Hitting "Apply" after unchecking it actually wipes the html-template directory!

Answer (score 0):

Doing a clean build of the project fixed this for me. This is on Flash Builder 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

The post marked as the answer is correct, but I have to add that you better make sure to have Write permissions on the html-template folder.

I had to run Flash Builder as Administrator for a bit, and accidentally rebuilt my project still as Administrator. Flash Builder wrecked havoc on my project folder's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Adobe Flash Builder 4.5

I had the same problem. The post marked as the answer is correct. If the solution won't work then click Problems icon in your Flash Builder and you will see some errors. After correcting the errors it will work fine.